# Thinking-Sphinx doesn't index anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

My environment:

```
Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard
Ruby 1.9.2p0
Rails 3.0.0
thinking-sphinx (2.0.0.rc1)
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
```

So far I haven't really been able to get anything to work.

```
pma:log pma$ rake thinking_sphinx:index
(in /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/vendor/plugins/yaml_db/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/Rakefile:7)
Generating Configuration to /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf'

pma:urban-ent pma$ rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild
(in /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/vendor/plugins/yaml_db/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/Rakefile:7)
Generating Configuration to /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/config/development.sphinx.conf'
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/log/searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /Users/pma/Sites/urban-ent/log/searchd.log
```

The searchd.log is empty. Nothing gets written to it.

```
pma:log pma$ ls -l
total 3312
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 pma  staff  1694487 Sep  8 15:17 development.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 pma  staff        0 Sep  7 14:57 production.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 pma  staff        0 Sep  7 17:39 searchd.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 pma  staff        0 Sep  7 14:57 server.log
-rw-rw-rw-  1 pma  staff        0 Sep  7 14:58 test.log
pma:log pma$
```

I do have indexes defined in a model at app/models/instruction.rb

```
define index do
  indexes title
  indexes description
end
```

They seem to be totally ignored though.

Solutions anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's a typo, but `define index` should be `define_index`